# setDefaultNightMode change is not restarting singleTop activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme

I have a settings activity that has an option to allow a user to switch between night and day mode using:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode();
```

This works great for almost all my activities as android will force a configuration change when this happens causing all activities to be restarted with the configuration change.

However I have one activity that is singleTop:

```
<activity
  android:name=".MyActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleTop" />
```

This activity does not see the configuration change and is not restarted.  If I remove singleTop the activity sees the configuration change and restarts.  Is this a bug in android?  I have updated to latest support library (27.1.0) and still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Well generally an activity with `singleTop` launch mode can be instantiated multiple times, but that's not always the case. Typically the instances are launched into the task that called `startActivity()`. But if the target task already has an existing instance of the activity at the top of its stack, the instance will receive the intent but a new instance of that activity will not be created. Hence the activity will not be restarted and will not see the configuration change. And since `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()` only takes effect for the components that are created after the call, so already created instances will not be updated.

For the activities which have launch mode `standard` which is the default mode, a new instance is created every time there is a new intent for those activities. And that is why you can see the activity to restart and configuration change when you remove `singleTop` mode.

Comment: 'AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode() only takes effect for the components that are created after the call' is that why rotation is picked up but not uiMode?

Comment: Yes. That is why. Since android system handles the rotation, active activity is going to pick it up, unless you have locked the orientation change on your activity.

Comment: True, but non active activities also pick up rotation and are recreated.  This is why uiMode not behaving the same way is very confusing.  So with a singleTop activity I must check in onResume if the uiMode has changed and recreate the activity on my own?

Comment: Yes that's how I would approach this if I really need the activity to be `singleTop`

Comment: or you can add flags to your intent for this activity like this `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)`